# Bootstrap alert from zend controller

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing with the zend skeleton application and I would like to display a bootstrap alert after creating/updating an album in case of success (once return on the album list).

Here is the controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function addAction()
{
    $form = new AlbumForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $album = new Album();
        $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);

            // Redirect to list of albums
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

According to you what is the best way to deal ?

Many thanks,
Cedric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the flashMessenger plugin to store your messages as an array and then loop through the array in your view (or better still a view helper) and generate the markup required for bootstrap stye messages.